# Executable Script Code Found in Signature Block Error

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, azure, azure-deployment

When using Visual Studio 2017 on a Windows 7 machine to deploy Azure ARM templates I recently started receiving an error stating that `Executable script code found in signature block` which appears only after the **second** deployment of a template. I found few sources that mentioned this error but none with an actual solution aside from closing and re-opening Visual Studio which really isn't an acceptable solution. I've included the full deploy log below:

```
17:40:53 - The following parameter values will be used for this operation:
17:40:53 -     AZTemplateTestName: AZTemplateTest-AppService
17:40:53 -     AZTemplateTestSkuName: S1
17:40:54 - Build started.
17:40:54 - Project "AZTemplateTest.deployproj" (StageArtifacts target(s)):
17:40:54 - Project "AZTemplateTest.deployproj" (ContentFilesProjectOutputGroup target(s)):
17:40:54 - Done building project "AZTemplateTest.deployproj".
17:40:54 - Done building project "AZTemplateTest.deployproj".
17:40:54 - Build succeeded.
17:40:54 - Launching PowerShell script with the following command:
17:40:54 - 'C:\Users\username\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\AZTemplateTest-Test\AZTemplateTest-Test\bin\Debug\staging\AZTemplateTest\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1' -StorageAccountName '' -ResourceGroupName 'AZTemplateTest-Test-2' -ResourceGroupLocation 'eastus' -TemplateFile 'C:\Users\username\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\AZTemplateTest-Test\AZTemplateTest-Test\bin\Debug\staging\AZTemplateTest\azuredeploy.json' -TemplateParametersFile 'C:\Users\username\documents\visual studio     2017\Projects\AZTemplateTest-Test\AZTemplateTest-Test\bin\Debug\staging\AZTemplateTest\azuredeploy.parameters.json' -ArtifactStagingDirectory '.' -DSCSourceFolder '.\DSC'
17:40:54 - [ERROR] At line:1 char:2337
+ $UI = 'VS-'; if (!(Test-Path 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Windows Azure P ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.
```

The more interesting part is that if I go to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming` the only folder that fits the pattern of `Windows Azure P` is `Windows Azure Powershell`. Inside that folder the only thing present is `AzureDataCollectionProfile.json` which only contains if I opted in or out of the Azure data collection. If I try deleting that file and/or the folder the results remain the same.

I've also tried the following in hopes of finding a solution:

- Created a new project entirely, same results
- Cleaning the project, same results
- Rebuilding the project, same results

Comment: are you in psversion 3 ?? COuld you pls let us know the PS version you are in

Comment: I think you have landed into a bug. One workaround would be to just call the PowerShell script directly instead of through VS. Use this tweak [TWEAK](https://github.com/pester/Pester/commit/92f94357bbce01caded6f3b3cfddbcb528f56436)

Comment: @RanadipDutta Yup, this is V3.

Comment: @RanadipDutta Any thoughts on where I can put that tweak/workaround in an Azure deployment script? Part of my issue is that I can't actually find the lines where the issue is stemming from.

Comment: While passing a string value to Set-Item in the function provider, you will get the issue . But if you use [scriptblock]::Create() , it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in PowerShell 3 on Win7 - the only fix we have is to upgrade PowerShell.